# How to find maximum value in struct array

Tags: matlab, matrix, struct

I have a struct that looks something like this:

```
data.index
data.x
data.y
```

It has anywhere from 1 to 100 elements that I can access with `data(Window_Size).y` (or whatever). What I want to do is compare all x values and all y values, independently, to get the maxX, maxY, minX, and minY.

I tried something like this

```
MaxX = max(data(:).x);
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated; I have absolutely zero experience with Matlab beyond the past few hours trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 4):

You’re almost there! Try this:

```
MaxX = max([data.x]);
```

`data.x` is a comma-separated list of all values in the `x` field. The `[]` concatenates them into a row array, sort of the same as `[data(1).x, data(2).x, ...]`.